# Modifying ethernet ports on device tree

Tags: embedded, network-interface, device-tree

We want to change the vitesse switch on mpc8308erdb with a ks8999 switch. And connect eTSEC0 and eTSEC1 to two separate ks8999 switches.

I want to know what files i should change in order for linux to work in this new condition.This switches are fast ethernet switches and connect to board with mii interfaces.(there is no mdio interface in them)

we changed device tree like this and checked switch functionality by checking its other ports but networking is not working.
unchanged device tree:

```
        enet0: ethernet@24000 {
            cell-index = <0>;
            device_type = "network";
            model = "eTSEC";
            compatible = "gianfar";
            reg = <0x24000 0x1000>;
            local-mac-address = [ 00 00 00 00 00 00 ];
            interrupts = <32 0x8 33 0x8 34 0x8>;
            interrupt-parent = <&ipic>;
            tbi-handle = <&tbi0>;
            phy-handle = < &phy0 >;
/*          sleep = <&pmc 0xc0000000>;  */
            fsl,magic-packet;
            fsl,lossless-flow-ctrl = <0>;
            ptimer-handle = < &ptp_timer >;
        };

        enet1: ethernet@25000 {
            cell-index = <1>;
            device_type = "network";
            model = "eTSEC";
            compatible = "gianfar";
            reg = <0x25000 0x1000>;
            local-mac-address = [ 00 00 00 00 00 00 ];
            interrupts = <35 0x8 36 0x8 37 0x8>;
            interrupt-parent = <&ipic>;
            /* tbi-handle = <&tbi1>; */
            /* phy-handle = < &phy1 >; */
            /* Vitesse 7385 isn't on the MDIO bus */
            fixed-link = <1 1 1000 0 0>;
/*          sleep = <&pmc 0x30000000>;  */
            fsl,magic-packet;
            fsl,lossless-flow-ctrl = <0>;
            ptimer-handle = < &ptp_timer >;
            phy-connection-type = "rgmii-id";
        };
```

changed device tree:

```
        enet0: ethernet@24000 {
            cell-index = <0>;
            device_type = "network";
            model = "eTSEC";
            compatible = "gianfar";
            reg = <0x24000 0x1000>;
            local-mac-address = [ 00 00 00 00 00 00 ];
            interrupts = <32 0x8 33 0x8 34 0x8>;
            interrupt-parent = <&ipic>;
            fixed-link = <2 1 100 0 0>;         
/*          sleep = <&pmc 0xc0000000>;  */
            fsl,magic-packet;
            fsl,lossless-flow-ctrl = <0>;
            ptimer-handle = < &ptp_timer >;
            phy-connection-type = "mii";
        };

        enet1: ethernet@25000 {
            cell-index = <1>;
            device_type = "network";
            model = "eTSEC";
            compatible = "gianfar";
            reg = <0x25000 0x1000>;
            local-mac-address = [ 00 00 00 00 00 00 ];
            interrupts = <35 0x8 36 0x8 37 0x8>;
            interrupt-parent = <&ipic>;
            fixed-link = <1 1 100 0 0>;
/*          sleep = <&pmc 0x30000000>;  */
            fsl,magic-packet;
            fsl,lossless-flow-ctrl = <0>;
            ptimer-handle = < &ptp_timer >;
            phy-connection-type = "mii";
        };
```

In reference board one eTSEC is connected to a phy and another is connected to a gigabit ethernet switch.